# TCP-Syn is not being answered

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I'm implementing TCP in Objective C and C.
When I send a Syn Packet to a server I do not get an answer.
A pcap file of the packet can be found here: <s>Tcp-Syn.pcap</s>

Is the packet malformed or am I missing some convention which leads to my packet being dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file in wireshark.

Go to **Edit->Preferences->Protocols->TCP** , enable "Validate the TCP checksum if possible"

You will find that the TCP checksum you've generated is wrong.

The MAC addresses in the ethernet headers are all 0 as well, which looks odd - where's this packet going to ?

Comment: I manually zeroed the MAC addresses in the file out, I'm kind of paranoid haha. I corrected my checksum implementation to use the TCP Pseudo header and now it works :)